# Does conditional indepence imply this?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

> **Definition**
>
> Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables for a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$
>
> Then, $X,Y$ are said to be **conditionally independent given $Z$** if $P(X\in A, Y\in B|Z)=P(X\in A|Z)P(Y\in B|Z)$ for all borel sets $A,B$.

If $X,Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$, $P(X\in A|Y,Z)= P(X\in A|Z)$?

This is **true** if we assume $(X,Y,Z)$ is jointly absolutely continuous. (Because $$p(x|z)=p(x|z)p(y|z)/p(y|z)=p(x,y|z)/p(y|z)=p(x,y|z)p(z)/p(y,z)=p(x,y,z)/p(y,z)=p(x|y,z)$$)

I am curious if this holds for general $X,Y,Z$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly true.

Let's say that the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent given $\mathcal{H}$ if

$$
P_{\mathcal{H}}(F \cap G) = P_{\mathcal{H}}(F) P_{\mathcal{H}}(G)
$$
for every $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}$.

Then we will show that
$$
P_{\mathcal{G} \vee \mathcal{H}}(F) = P_{\mathcal{H}}(F)
$$
for every $F \in \mathcal{F}$.

First $P_{\mathcal{H}}(F)$ is certainly $(\mathcal{G} \vee \mathcal{H})$-measurable.

Second, we have, for every $F \in \mathcal{F}$, $G \in \mathcal{G}$ and
$H \in \mathcal{H}$,

\begin{align}
P(F \cap G \cap H) &=  E( P_{\mathcal{H}}(F) P_{\mathcal{H}}(G) I_{H})\\\\ 
&= E( P_{\mathcal{H}}(F) P_{\mathcal{H}}(G \cap H)) \\\\
&= E( P_{\mathcal{H}}(F) I_{G \cap H})
\end{align}
where the first equality comes from the conditional independence of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$.
Since the equality $P(F \cap G \cap H) = E( P_{\mathcal{H}}(F) I_{G \cap H})$ is true for every set of the form $G \cap H$, it will be true for every set in $\mathcal{G} \vee \mathcal{H}$, by standard arguments.

Comment: What's $P_\mathscr{H}(A)$? Do you mean $P(A|\mathscr{H})$?

Comment: Yes sure ......